# Как сделать первую букву имени заглавной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно сделать первую букву имени заглавной. Я пытаюсь сделать это через присвоения значения, на что получаю исключения вида: TypeError.

На языке C# такая операция допустима, а здесь получается нельзя присвоить значение одному элементу типа str?

Напишите, пожалуйста, как минимум два возможных способа капитализации первой буквы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем набрасываться как стервятник @strawdog? вы серьезно решили  вместо того чтобы просто пожаловаться на вопрос, написать свое бесполезное сообщение в комментариях?

Comment: @ЯнМорозов мне не нужно жаловаться на вопрос. я могу прямо голосовать за его закрытие. Мое сообщение призвано обратить внимание автора вопроса не необходимость учиться самому, а не ждать, когда на элементарные вопросы ему ответят такие как вы. На будущее: не утруждайте себя в написании подобных комментариев в мой адрес.

Comment: @strawdog опять вы решили написать свой бесполезный скулеж в комментариях, вам делать нечего:))). Вместо того чтобы заниматься ерундой порекомендуйте человеку книжку или статью где можно найти ответ на вопрос, не занимайтесь клоунадой. Спасибо. На будущее не утруждайте себя высиранием бесполезных коментариев, не знаете что написать не пишите ничего.

Comment: @strawdog В первую очередь я только начал изучать python и пользуюсь сайтом METANIT. Может где-то и написано про это, но я как минимум до этого еще не дошел. Пока я учусь, мне нужна практика, поэтому делаю небольшие программки. И задал я этот вопрос с целью узнать, почему так сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно брать всю строку

```
name = name.capitalize()
```

Второй способ

```
name = name[0].upper()+name[1:]
```

Answer (score 3):

> На языке C# такая операция допустима

Вы ошибаетесь. И в `Python` и в `C#` строки одинаково иммутабельны (и не только в этих языках), вы не можете изменить один символ прямо внутри строки, как вы пытаетесь сделать присвоением `name[0] = ...`, вам обязательно придётся создавать новую строку, изменённую нужным образом, и присваивать эту строку целиком в переменную `name = ...`

Comment: Согласен, я что-то перепутал с C#. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы написать строку с заглавной буквы вы можете использовать:

```py
my_string = "nikita"
    
print(my_string.title())
```